# RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide distances = 1 - 0.5 * X @ self.X_T / np.linalg.norm(X, axis=1)[:, None] / self.X_T_norm

Tags: python, runtime-error

I'm trying to run predicted_labels:

```
def test_ensemble_labels(train_data, y, test_data, vector_names, NNeighbours, lower, upper):
    y_pred = []
    for j in range(len(vector_names)):
        y_pred.append(frnn_owa_method(train_data, y, test_data, vector_names[j], NNeighbours[j], lower, upper)[1])
    # Use voting function to obtain the ensembled label - we used mean
    y_pred_res = np.mean(y_pred, axis=0)
    return y_pred_res 

predicted_labels = test_ensemble_labels(data, data['Label'], test_data, ["Vector_d2v"], [19], additive(), additive())
```

But I get a message:

```
/content/frnn_owa_eval.py:33: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  distances = 1 - 0.5 * X @ self.X_T / np.linalg.norm(X, axis=1)[:, None] / self.X_T_norm
```

This is a function containing distances:

```
def _query(self, X, m_int: int):
            distances = 1 - 0.5 * X @ self.X_T / np.linalg.norm(X, axis=1)[:, None] / self.X_T_norm
            return least_indices_and_values(distances, m_int, axis=-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to execute classic "divide by zero" or "divide by NaN". Preprocess your dataset/variables to check these conditions beforehand.

If you don't want to do that, you can bypass using this:

```
import numpy as np
np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')
```